# typeAhead for default values on click

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, xpages

Nice use case for edit fields with type ahead allows to click into empty field or to use alt+down shortcut, and list of recent/default values is provided. User does not need to **guess** what letter to type and has useful list of choices to start with.

**Question:** how can I invoke field's typeAhead partial refresh event when user enters/clicks to empty field, or uses alt+down? I expect submited variable defined by "var" property will be empty, I will handle it in code to get proper choices.

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputTextLookup"
    styleClass="lotusText"
    value="#{viewScope.znalostiLookup}">
    <xp:typeAhead
        mode="partial"
        minChars="1"
        var="valueToLookup"
        ignoreCase="true"
        preventFiltering="true"
        valueMarkup="true"
        maxValues="10">
        <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:return options(valueToLookup);}]]></xp:this.valueList>
    </xp:typeAhead>
</xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this f.e. by using the *onFocus* event of the inputText field.

```
<xp:eventHandler
   event="onfocus"
   submit="false">
   <xp:this.script>
      <![CDATA[
         var typeAhead = dijit.byId('#{id:inputTextLookup}');
         typeAhead._startSearch("ONFOCUS");
      ]]>
   </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

The parameter of the _*startSearch()* method is the value send to the server.